# Could one outgrow one's wand?

Tags: harry-potter, wandlore

Within the Harry Potter canon, it is firmly established that the wand chooses the wizard.  Certain types of wands favour certain personality types (for example, a short wand will likely be suited to someone whose personality is lacking in some respect).

But the average witch or wizard chooses their wand when they are only 11 years old.  One's personality is hardly set in stone at age 11, and it is possible (if not likely) that one's personality will drastically change as they approach adulthood.

Clearly this is not a problem for most witches and wizards, but is it possible for one to grow up and develop a personality that is incompatible with their wand?

Comment: Given that many powerful wizards *upgrade* their wands when they reach adulthood, it seems quite likely that if your personality shifts away from a wand's material, you'd just go to Ollivander and tell him you need a new one because your current one isn't working very well.

Comment: The bond between wand and wizard also grows stronger over time, which is the key thing. Wand compatibility isn't an exact science. Like sorting, it can be superceded by events but it doesn't mean the wand won't work. As Ollivander says, wizards can use pretty much any wand. Their chosen wand just gives them the best results.

Comment: But are the wands not deemed to be more skilled at making the right choice? I.e. maybe humans (both wizard and muggle) can't see the future of an 11 year old. But wands will presumably be able to see the character of the person (because how else would they be able to choose? They must have some way of observing the worthiness of a wizard), and if wands are intelligent enough; they can understand what the future of this person will hold (e.g. Draco is a dick, and will therefore have many enemies in his future) While people's lives change as they age, their _character_ usually stays the same.

Comment: @Flater I think that making a better choice than an 11 year old budding wizards is probably different than doing that with an experienced wizard who knows what she/he wants.

Comment: @MishaR: As far as I'm aware there is no canon reference to young wizards being more flexibly assigned to their wands. Similarly, the sorting hat has the same skill, and it specifically classifies young wizard's characters at the start of their first year, before any training has taking place.

Comment: @Flater Right. They're children, so the sorting hat and the wand might know better. My hope is that that changes when they're adults with some education and experience behind them. I don't think we need an explicit canon confirmation that there is a difference between adults and children among wizards.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Mr. Ollivander notes have a few interesting things to say on this... but first off, remember:

1. Wand making is a family guarded secret.
2. Ollivander is considered the almost unarguably the best.
3. He freely admit he does not fully understand wand-lore.

> The best wands, he believed, had cores of immensely powerful magical substances, which were expertly enclosed in specially selected and complementary wandwoods, the result to be **matched to an owner with whom the wand itself felt the most affinity.**
>
> ...
>
> His methods of locating wand woods and core substances marrying them together and matching them to ideal owners are all jealously guarded secrets that were coveted by rival wandmakers.
>
> *([Mr. Ollivander](https://www.pottermore.com/writing-by-jk-rowling/mr-ollivander) on Pottermore by JK Rowling)*

> Every single wand is unique and will depend for its character on the particular tree and magical creature from which it derives its materials. **Moreover, each wand, from the moment it finds its ideal owner, will begin to learn from and teach its human partner.**
>
> ...
>
> The following notes on various wand woods should be regarded very much as a starting point, for this is the study of a lifetime, and I continue to learn with every wand I make and match.
>
> *([Wand Woods](https://www.pottermore.com/writing-by-jk-rowling/wand-woods) on Pottermore by JK Rowling)*

> Readers should bear in mind that each wand is the composite of its wood, its core and the experience and **nature of its owner**; that tendencies of each may counterbalance or outweigh the other; so this can only be a very general overview of an immensely complex subject.
>
> *([Wand Cores](https://www.pottermore.com/writing-by-jk-rowling/wand-cores) on Pottermore by JK Rowling)*

> However, no single aspect of wand composition should be considered in isolation of all the others, and the type of wood, the core and the flexibility may either counterbalance or enhance the attributes of the wand’s length.
>
> ...
>
> Wand flexibility or rigidity denotes the degree of adaptability and willingness to change possessed by the wand-and-owner pair - although, again, this factor ought not to be considered separately from the wand wood, core and length, nor of **the owner’s life experience and style of magic, all of which will combine to make the wand in question unique.**
>
> *([Wand Lengths & Flexibility](https://www.pottermore.com/writing-by-jk-rowling/wand-lengths-and-flexibilit) on Pottermore by JK Rowling)*

TL;DR **To summarize, while a wizard may replace their wand (as we see Charlie Weasley do) they will not "out grow" it.  Each wand owner has a very unique instrument and the wand will learn and grow with the wizard.**

Comment: What do we know about Charlie Weasley's wand exactly?

Comment: @thedarklord  That Ron uses it when he goes to Hogwarts

Answer (score 0):

## In the vast majority of cases, the wand ‘grows’ with the wizard.

After a wizard first gets their wand, as they use it, their wand learns and grows with them. For most wizards, this means their wand becomes more, not less, suited to them as they grow.

> “The best results, however, must always come where there is the strongest affinity between wizard and wand. These connections are complex. An initial attraction, and then a mutual quest for experience, the wand learning from the wizard, the wizard from the wand.” 
> <sub><sup>*- Harry Potter and the Deathly Hallows, Chapter 24 (The Wandmaker)*</sup></sub>

Though there’s no instances we know of where a wizard changed so drastically and quickly that they outgrow their wand, it may be theoretically possible, and if it were to happen (perhaps caused by some incident that totally changes them), presumably the wizard would just buy a new wand.